# docx to png converter using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

while converting docx to png using docx4j getting UnsupportedOperationException . Below are the sample code.

```
public class DocToPng {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException, IOException {
    String inPath="D:\\pdfconverterfolder\\test.docx";
    String outPath="D:\\pdfconverterfolder\\pngOutput.png";
     File theFile = new File(inPath);
    File outile=new File(outPath);
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPckg = Docx4J.load(theFile);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outile);
    FOSettings settings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
    settings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPckg);
    settings.setApacheFopMime("images/png");
    Docx4J.toFO(settings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
    os.close();
    System.out.println("DOne");
}
}
```

and below are the console output:

```
[main] INFO org.docx4j.org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream - Using repackaged ToXMLStream
[main] INFO org.docx4j.org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream - Using repackaged ToXMLStream
[main] ERROR org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter - Exception exporting package
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Don't know how to handle "images/png" as an output format. Neither an FOEventHandler, nor a Renderer could be found for this output format.
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createFOEventHandler(RendererFactory.java:365)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.<init>(FOTreeBuilder.java:107)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.createDefaultHandler(Fop.java:104)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.<init>(Fop.java:78)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.newFop(FOUserAgent.java:182)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newFop(FopFactory.java:219)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:240)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:187)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:82)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:689)
    at toImage.DocToPng.main(DocToPng.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:689)
    at toImage.DocToPng.main(DocToPng.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Don't know how to handle "images/png" as an output format. Neither an FOEventHandler, nor a Renderer could be found for this output format.
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createFOEventHandler(RendererFactory.java:365)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.<init>(FOTreeBuilder.java:107)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.createDefaultHandler(Fop.java:104)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.<init>(Fop.java:78)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.newFop(FOUserAgent.java:182)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newFop(FopFactory.java:219)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:240)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:187)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:82)
    ... 2 more
```

looks like docx4j doesn't support to convert into any image format.Any suggestion.? Thanks.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export docx to png using docx4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328879/how-to-export-docx-to-png-using-docx4j)

Comment: As per above link solution, i have already added below maven dependency but still getting the UnsupportedOperationException. <dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    settings.setApacheFopMime(MimeConstants.MIME_PNG);
```

works for me.

I guess the problem is that you have "images/png", not "image/png"

Comment: Any idea how this conversion can be done for multiple pages in the docx, it only converts the first page, I want this to happen to all the pages.